# Numerical integration yields errors

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

I try the following simple calculation but Mathematica gives me some errors. I am not sure why I get these error messages and if the calculation is correct after all, I'd appreciate some feedback.

Code:

test[z_] := NIntegrate[1/(x^5 + 3), {x, 0, z}]

result = NIntegrate[test[z], {z, 0, 4}]

[image]

Comment: `test[z_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[1/(x^5 + 3), {x, 0, z}];
NIntegrate[test[z], {z, 0, 4}]`

Answer (score 5):

If you use two-dimensional integration you will get a result without messages:

```
In[2]:= NIntegrate[1/(x^5 + 3), {z, 0, 4}, {x, 0, z}]
Out[2]= 1.43507
```

*(Voting to close as "easily found in the documentation.")*

Comment: Thank you very much!